# How do I render a jinja2 template within the context of a single object

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a bunch of jinja2 templates, and each template only has variables that are tied to attributes of a single object at a time.

For example, I'd like to render the template `{{foo}} {{bar}}` using an object that has the two properties `foo` and `bar`.

Conventionally, I'd do this with `Template("{{obj.foo}} {{obj.bar}}").render(obj=SomeObject())` but I'd like to reduce the `obj.` duplication in the template.

Comment: I guess you could use `.render(**obj.__dict__)`, but surely it's better to be explicit?

Comment: That won't work for me because I actually depend on the use of `getattr` for object attributes as some of these attributes are lazily created. The reason I want it to be implicit is for brevity as they will be provided via a config file.